# Source model "buyer/product_attribute_source_buyer" not found for attribute "buyer_name"

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

Source model "buyer/product_attribute_source_buyer" not found for attribute "buyer_name"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Limex_Buyer>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Limex_Buyer>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Buyer.php

```
<?php
class Limex_Buyer_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Buyer extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract
{
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (!$this->_options) {
            $this->_options = array(
                array(
                    'value' => '',
                    'label' => '',
                ),
                array(
                    'value' => '1',
                    'label' => 'Day',
                ),
                array(
                    'value' => '2',
                    'label' => 'Week',
                ),
                array(
                    'value' => '3',
                    'label' => 'Month',
                ),
                array(
                    'value' => '4',
                    'label' => 'Year',
                )
            );
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
?>
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Limex_Buyer>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Limex_Buyer>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <buyer>
            <class>Limex_Buyer_Block</class>
        </buyer>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <buyer>
            <class>Limex_Buyer_Helper</class>
        </buyer>
    </helpers>
    <models>
        <buyer>
            <class>Limex_Buyer_Model</class>
        </buyer>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <buyer_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Limex_Buyer</module>
                <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </buyer_setup>
    </resources>

</global>
```

Comment: First clear the cache. Then make sure that `Buyer.php` is located in `app/code/local/Limex/Buyer/Model/Product/Attribute/Source/` folder.

Comment: Please check compiler is enable or not?